# What is the difference between activating content/page and publishing page in AEM?

Tags: aem

When we publish a page again we need to activate content in tools. I just need difference and use case. What is difference between activating content/page and publishing a page in AEM?

Comment: Both are same, [Per reference link](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/experience-manager/6-4/sites/classic-ui-authoring/using/classic-page-author-publish-pages.html). Activate / Deactivate -These terms are synonymous with publish/unpublish.

Answer (score 1):

From Adobe Docs -

> Certain terms related to publishing can be confused:
>
> **Publish / Unpublish** These are the primary terms for the actions that
>   make your content publicly available on your publish environment (or
>   not).
>
> **Activate / Deactivate** These terms are synonymous with
>   publish/unpublish.
>
> **Replicate / Replication** These are the technical terms describing the
>   movement of data (e.g. page content, files, code, user comments) from
>   one environment to another such as when publishing or
>   reverse-replicating user comments.

Activate/Deactivate were the terminologies used in classic UI, you can see this on any version of AEM if you invoke the old screens - go to `http://localhost:4502/siteadmin` or use `cf#` to edit the page (`http://localhost:4502/cf#/content/app/en.html`) and go to page properties in side kick, you'll notice Activate/Deactivate.

On Touch UI, you'll notice Publish/unpublish, check page properties using the `editor.html`(http://localhost:4502/editor.html/content/app/en.html) or any other console in Touch UI.

They both mean the same - moving data from author environment to publish environment. Taking it a step further, it can also mean moving data from author to the dispatcher(via the publisher), with an added flexibility of clearing cache for that page during publishing/activating.